# NEHotspotConfigurationManager Can it get the WiFi list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

iOS released the public API NEHotspot ConfigurationManager

Inside there is a function: `getConfiguredSSIDs (completionHandler: ([String]) -> Void)`

Do not know the return value of this, my Code like:

## Code :

```
[[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] getConfiguredSSIDsWithCompletionHandler: ^ (NSArray * array) {

            
             NSLog (@ "Response:% @", array);

           
         }];
```

However, the value is null .. Why?

Is there any way to get nearby WiFi using NEHotspotConfigurationManager without going through NEHotspotHelper?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons your app only has access to SSIDs that your app itself has configured.

To configure a wifi network you need to enable the Hotspot Configuration entitlement in your app settings and then call:

```
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply()
```

It's also worth noting that if the user has already manually joined the wifi network outside of your app when your app tries to join that network you will get an error stating that they are already a member and it won't show up in the ConfiguredSSIDs list, so try to support this as well.