# Delphi Firemonkey IOS get current SSID

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, ssid

Hello this is driving me nuts, I want to
Get the current SSID in my IOS app. I am using Delphi11 and the target is an iPhone 8 Plus on IOS 15.3.1.
I read all kind of info but nothing leads to a useful result, please help,
Kind regards

Comment: Apple have tightened up on apps being able to retrieve SSIDs. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111386/nehotspotconfigurationmanager-can-it-get-the-wifi-list), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583650/cncopycurrentnetworkinfo-with-ios-13). It might help to describe *why* you want to obtain the SSID

Comment: The wi-fi target is an esp01s, this device only works on 2.4GHz,so the ultimate go is to get the SSID and its properties. I can off course let the app user look-up this info on the iPhone but it seems to me more user-friendly to display this in the app itself. The links you provided are very useful thank you very much. My problem is that I would like to translate the code to Delphi firemonkey.